# How to add 2 objects or more to one JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe

I tried looking but no questions were helpful.
Here's my code to begin with:

```
    Player player = new Player();
    Block1 block1 = new Block1();
    JFrame ow = new JFrame();
    ow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ow.setSize(500,500);
    ow.setTitle("My Game");
    ow.setVisible(true);
    ow.setLocation(400, 100);
    ow.add(block1);
    ow.add(player);
```

but it will only add the last one, someone said (when I searched old questions) that it erases the previous one because they are both in the same location.
So I modified it this way:

```
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setSize(500, 500);
    Player player = new Player();
    Block1 block1 = new Block1();
    JFrame ow = new JFrame();
    jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jp.add(player);
    jp.add(block1);
    ow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ow.setSize(500,500);
    ow.setTitle("My Game");
    ow.setVisible(true);
    ow.setLocation(400, 100);
    ow.add(jp);
```

It did work, putting them both visible but... it sort of made two square panels so I can't go near `block 1` with my `player`.
Any help?

Comment: `ow.add(someComponent, BorderLayout.SOUTH)`

Comment: Try to experiment with different layouts to meet your needs

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Tried all of what you said, not working :(

Comment: Can you bring us a draw of what it should look like? I can't still figure out what you're trying to do

Comment: http://postimg.org/image /71ok93lin/
Sorry for the lousy painting (No spaces).

Comment: and what are you getting instead? (screen shot would be fine)

Comment: Now it's not working at all but I get the player and the block but when the player goes up a specific range around the block then it is gone behind some panel.

Answer (score 2):

JFrame by default uses [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). If you don't specify where you will put the component, it's going to be put in `BorderLayout.CENTER`. You can't put 2 or more components in the same position. To prevent this undesired behaviour you have to set different constraints.

For example:

```
jframe.add(someComponent, BorderLayout.LINE_END);//constraint indicating position
```

Read more in tutorials : [How to use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

If this layout don't fit what you need, try to use another LayoutManager or mix them.

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Tried but it's like two different screen, I didn't get the player to be near block1.

Comment: What do you want your screen gonna to be? if you want one next another you can use `FlowLayout`

Comment: Tried that too, not working though. I want it to be one screen but multiple objects.

Comment: Can you write a simple code like mine which is working the way I wanted? Assume player and block1 are already announced.

Comment: @user3220493 i don't get what you want.. If you use a proper layout or combination of them you sure can achieve what you want, take a look of `A visual Guide to LayoutManager..`

Comment: I want to create a screen with two objects - player and a block, them both are squarish. I want them to not just appear on the same screen, but be able to come near each other and touch each other.

Comment: @user3220493 Then you have to do some sort of animation that is not related to this question. Im not an expert but i think you have to use a `SwingTimer` override `paintComponent` in your `JComponent`